# Pegar valor de um campo hidden fora do laço php

Tags: jquery

Colegas

Tenho um código em php que traz do banco o valor do produto.

```
<?php
...
while($jmMostrar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlMostrar)){
      $mostrar = "<input type='hidden' id='produtos' name='valorProduto' value='".$jmMostrar->ValorProduto."'>";
}
```

Cada $jmMostrar->ValorProduto traz um valor diferenciado. Como eu faria para pegar esses valores com jquery? Tentei dessa forma, mas ele só me traz o primeiro valor:

```
$('.value-plus').on('click', function(){
var qtdCarrinho = $("#qtdCarrinho").val();
```

Comment: Fox dentro do while não quererás fazer uma concatenação (`$mostrar .= "...`) ou é mesmo isso que queres?

Comment: Olá Miguel. Na verdade ele já está concatenado. Coloquei aqui apenas como forma de exemplo. Preciso pegar o valor do produto e jogar para dentro de um jquery fora do laço PHP.

Comment: Ha ok percebi, nesse caso acho que já tens a resposta do @Alison que faz isso. MAS muita atenção não deves ter ids repetidos no DOM... A minha sugestão é trocares para class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode-se pegar assim:

```
//NOME-DO-CAMPO-HIDDEN
$("input[name='valorProduto']").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() !== undefined){
      alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Olá Alisson. Infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: @Fox.11 retorna o que no alert ?

Comment: @Fox.11 troquei o código, tenta lá

Comment: funcionou sim, mas quando tem 02 valores, ele retorna 03 sendo esse último como indefinido...

Comment: @Fox.11 coloqui uma verificação

Comment: perfeito.. funcionou... Muito obrigado!

Comment: Só posso aceitar sua resposta daqui a 03 minutos, mas voltarei para aceitar..rs rs obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado @Fox.11